# Webcomponent Initialization Failed, Details: TypeError: object doesn't support property or method 'initialize'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, smartcard-reader

"ActiveX is not supported by this browser, please use Internet Explorer". But am using internet explorer only. And  I tried many times this ActiveX issue by setting the internet options enabled all ActiveX setting  and java [control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyGmJ.png) also did properly..it doesn't working ..am using windows 10 internet explorer version 21H2

[Webcomponent Initialization Failed, Details: TypeError: object doesn't support property or method 'initialize'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyGmJ.png)

Comment: Does this issue only occur in specific site? Have you tried restting IE? Just refer to [this doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-or-reset-internet-explorer-settings-2d4bac50-5762-91c5-a057-a922533f77d5).

Comment: That image looks a bit suspicious - certainly the dialog doesn't look like a Microsoft error dialog.